# How do I create an array (which I can query against) of existing jQuery-objects

Tags: jquery

I have following code

```
var $radio1 = $('#FOO1');
var $radio2 = $('#FOO2');
var $radio3 = $('#FOO3');
```

Now I would like to to sth like

```
var $radios = $($radio1, $radio2, $radio3);
var $selectedRadio = $radios.filter(':checked');
```

I know that this won't work, but could anyone give me a hand with this?

**To clarify:**

- I do not want to use `jQuery.each` or any alikes as I would like to use selectors (if possible)...
- I do not want to use `groups`, as I would like to use this with several groups, or no groups, ...
- I do not want to use `id-selectors` for the array (eg. `$('#FOO1, #FOO2, #FOO3');`), as I would like a more generic solution

Comment: if you don't want to use id-selectors, what will you use?

Comment: @caspar: id-selectors for the array :) eg. `$('#FOO1, #FOO2, #FOO3');`. thanks, edited/corrected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine it in several ways:

```
var $radios = $("#FOO1, #FOO2, #FOO3");
var $selectedRadio = $radios.filter(':checked');
```

or

```
var $selectedRadio = $radio1.add($radio2).add($radio3).filter(':checked');
```

Comment: :) ... the first solution won't work in my situation ... but i will try the second one!

Comment: will this change the content of $radio1?